# Element Width Between Float Elements

Tags: css

I'm a noob to web dev and have a question:

I have a container that contains 4 inline elements: two buttons floating to the left, one button floating to the right, and a search box in the middle. The buttons have predefined dimensions (percentages of the container). I am trying to avoid giving the search box a predefined width, instead I would like the width of the search box to occupy as much space as it can between the floating elements on each side (refer to photo) such that it is more dynamic.

Is there any width setting technique to achieve this? I've tried adding all 3 buttons in HTML before adding the search box and then I've tried using the margin-left and margin-right value to hopefully stretch the search box. I've had no luck with this. Any help?

[image: Search Box Center]

HTML

```
        <div class = "SearchBox">
            <input type="image" src="./Home Page Resources/ChapterIcon.png" onclick="alert('Trigger Upload Page')">
            <input type="image" src="./Home Page Resources/UserSearchIcon-2.png" onclick="alert('Trigger Upload Page')">
            <input type="image" src="./Home Page Resources/SearchIcon-2.png" onclick="alert('Trigger Upload Page')">
            <input type="text" name="search">
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.SearchBox { 


display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float: right;
min-width: 35%;
height: 40px;
border: thin solid #80501F;
background-image: url("../Home Page Resources/WoodBackground-2.jpg");

border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;

}

.SearchBox input:nth-of-type(1) {
position: relative;
float:left;
width: 35px;
top: 3px;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 0%;
}

.SearchBox input:nth-of-type(2) {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 38px;
top: 0px;
margin-left: 0%;
margin-right: 0%;
}

.SearchBox  input:nth-of-type(3){

height: 25px;
display: inline;
float: right;
position: relative;
top: 8px;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;

}

.SearchBox  input:nth-of-type(4){

display: inline;
padding-left: 5px;
height: 25px;
font-family: 'Arial Black';
font-size: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: auto;



position: relative;
top: 4px;

border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Sounds very vague, Could you provide some code? And.. are you looking for `width:calc(100% - a - b -c); ` (Replace a b c with the width of the other 3 items in px. + margins

Comment: Sorry about that, please view the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `display:table` on a container and `display: table-cell` on each nested element.

For example, here's the HTML:

```
<div class="content">

  <ul>
    <li class="icon">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="icon">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="search"><input type="text"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.content {
  width: 600px;
  background: green;
}

ul {
  background: gray;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li.icon {
  background: red;
  width: 10%;
}

li.search {
  width: 80%;
}

li.search input {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/mknkz32p/